# Compile GhostScript 9.07 share library on Mac

Tags: ghostscript

I builded GhostScript 9.07 as share library.

./configure --prefix=/install/dir/
make so
make soinstall

compile and install stage are happy, but when i run ./gsc command appear some error messages

dyld: Library not loaded: libgs.dylib.9.07
  Referenced from: /install/dir/./gsc
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5

someone can help me? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the dylib file is actually installed?

If so, does it work correctly if you force pre-loading of the library file (LD_PRELOAD)?

If that works, does your linker search path include the directory where the dylib is installed?

Chirs